# .Net MAUI - LiveCharts - Custom point color in LineSeries

Tags: c#, maui, livecharts

I'm using LiveCharts v2 in .net MAUI app. I need to display temprature using chart and change point color when temperature > 38. In WPF i can use CartesianMapper and LineSeries.Configuration, but in .net MAUI i can't find LineSeries.Configuration. So, how to change point color?

I've tried LineSeries.Mapping, but i don't know how to change ChartPoint color?
`

```
lineSeries.Mapping = (value, point) =>
                        {
                            if (value > 37)
                            {
                                //lineSeries.DataLabelsPaint = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.Red);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                
                            }
                            point.PrimaryValue = value;
                            point.SecondaryValue = point.Context.Entity.EntityIndex;
                            
                        };
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LiveCharts2 is based on LiveCharts but the API is a little bit different, this feature is now called `ConditionalDraw` and while it is not properly documented yet, you can get info about it [here](https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/LiveCharts2/releases).

```
// full code at 
// https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/LiveCharts2/blob/master/samples/ViewModelsSamples/General/ConditionalDraw/ViewModel.cs
var series1 = new ColumnSeries<ObservableValue>
{
    Name = "Mary",
    Values = new ObservableValue[] { ... }
}
.WithConditionalPaint(new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.Black.WithAlpha(50)))
.When(point => point.Model?.Value > 5);
```

I think changing the color of the labels is not supported by now, I will take deeper look into that and update the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I also need change color of label and line. At this time, I'll use three LineSeries to achieve this. Hope you can improve in the future.